# Android Panorama viewing

Tags: android

Since i began programmation this forum provides me all that i always need! i want to thank you for... Thanks for all!!!!
Now i'm here to asking a problem that i not found it yet here.
I'm working on an android application. In my app, i have to read an android panorama which must be on a distant server. I have two problems to do  this and hope u to save:
1. I take a panorama from my phone and When i connect it to PC from copying my panorama, this one become a simple jpeg image. I don't know how and why!!!
2. I have no idea on how to view panorama on android. I search on google, on android forums and still at my beginning point, i have to present my application next week!!!

So i give myself to you for bringing me out from this depth.
Thanks.

Comment: what should a panorama be if not a simple very width image ? or do you mean something like in google street view (360° view)?

Comment: Not until google street view. Just something like that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ED-8bVLuEI

Comment: https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/android/ 

just a moment somewhere i have a sample code

Comment: sorry cant find it but maybe this helps u .. https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/

Comment: Thanks for your answers and sorry for this late. In fact it's something like that. I tried it and it's cool but it uses 6 different pictures. In my app i'm using mysql as DB so it will be delicate to load 6 pictures for show just one panorama if i had a lot!

Comment: When i run the example code "PanoraGL" it run correctly and for few second and give me this error back: Fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 15009 (FinalizerDaemon). what's that??

Answer (score 2):

there's this library that do that with spherical cubic and cylindrical panoramic images[PanoramaGL](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/)

and there's the utility with the google Play Services libs but only for spheric images refer to this : 
[Android Support for Photo Sphere](https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/android/)

Comment: does it mean google play service only supports images captured using google camera app? my images captured in nexus works just fine, howerver i am unable to successfully launch any other image in android panorama api

Comment: @Calvin android since 4.2 Google provided a new MIME type for pictures that can use the panorama (application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg), so you can't show all pictures in the Google panorama.

Comment: Yes found out that images need to have gpano related metadata in it for google to successfully load it